# Convert array to list and remove strings

Tags: python, arrays, list

How do I convert the array to list of integers (using Numpy or not)?

When pulling data from the array, I got the following result
e = ['100' '88' '45' '59' '73' '89']

Then I converted the array to the list using .tolist() function to get the following output

```
e = ['100', '88', '45', '59', '73', '89']
```

Now when I am trying to remove quotes surrounding items in the list '' using list(map(int,e), I am getting 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error. 
Please help me resolve this problem.

```
e = a[1:,1]
e = e.tolist()
e = list(map(int,e))
```

Comment: Tagging your question with the used programming language will increase your chances to get help

Comment: Most likely you have stored an np.array in a variable called `list` (or `map`) so you've overwritten the function with the same name. Calling `list` when it's an np.array instead of a function won't work. Other than that, your existing code should work.

Comment: What does `print(repr(list), type(list), repr(map), type(map))` say?

Answer (score 2):

Simple `list-comrehension` would work here:

```
e = ['100', '88', '45', '59', '73', '89']
e = [int(i) for i in e]
print(e)
```

Output:

```
[100, 88, 45, 59, 73, 89]
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than a list comprehension, `map` would work here:

```
e = ['100', '88', '45', '59', '73', '89']
e = list(map(int, e))
print(e) # [100, 88, 45, 59, 73, 89]
```

The reason you are getting this error with your code is you have overwritten `list` or `map` somewhere (most likely `list`, that mistake's pretty common). In effect, you are doing something similar to this:

```
list = 42
list('foo')
```

which reduces to

```
42('foo')
```

which will produce an `int not callable` error. In your case, you redefined `list` or `map` as a numpy array.

Comment: Well, it would work normally, but it's the exact same code he has included in the question that he is having problems with.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Whoops, I didn't even see that! I'll add some extra stuff to my answer to show what OP needs to change in their code.